# incompatible types when returning a Class

Tags: java

I'm using an external library over which I have no control.
It requires me to implement a method,
but I don't know how to return the type that is required:

```
@Override
public Optional<Class<? extends AnInterface<?>>> getCustomClass() {
    return Optional.of(MyClass.class);
    // compiler is giving error at the above line:
    // error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    // equality constraints: Class<? extends AnInterface<?>>
    // lower bounds: Class<MyClass>
    // where T is a type-variable:
    //   T extends Object declared in method <T>of(T)
}
```

MyClass:

```
public MyClass implements AnInterface<String> {
    ...
}
```

I tried this as well,
but it doesn't work:

```
@Override
public Optional<Class<? extends AnInterface<?>>> getCustomClass() {
    Optional<Class<? extends AnInterface<?>> clazz = MyClass.class;
    // this time the compiler gives error at the above line:
    // error: incompatible types: Class<MyClass> cannot be converted to Class<? extends AnInterface<?>>
    return clazz;
}
```

Also tried another one which doesn't work either:

```
@Override
public Optional<Class<? extends AnInterface<?>>> getCustomClass() {
    Optional<Class<? extends AnInterface> clazz = MyClass.class;
    return clazz;
    // this time the compiler gives error at the above line:
    // error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    // equality constraints: Class<? extends PropertyEditor<?>>
    // lower bounds: Class<CAP#1>
    // where T is a type-variable:
    //   T extends Object declared in method <T>of(T)
    // where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    //   CAP#1 extends PropertyEditor from capture of ? extends PropertyEditor
}
```

Any idea how to return the custom class please?

**JDK version: 8u77**

---

EDIT: The classes are nested like this:

```
public abstract class ParentClass<T> {
    public abstract T method();

    public class ImplementationClass implements ExternalLibraryInterface {
        @Override
        public Optional<Class<? extends AnotherExternalLibraryInterface<?>>> getCustomClass() {
            return Optional.of(MyClass.class);
            // compiler is giving error at the above line:
            // error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
            // equality constraints: Class<? extends AnotherExternalLibraryInterface<?>>
            // lower bounds: Class<MyClass>
            // where T is a type-variable:
            //   T extends Object declared in method <T>of(T)
        }

        MyClass implements AnotherExternalLibraryInterface<String>{
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

So for some reason the compiler is confused by the wildcard when implementing the overridden method of the external interface. After moving all the classes into their own files everything works fine.

However @Zefick's first solution actually works in the nested classes situation, I will mark it as resolved:

```
return (Optional)(Optional.of(MyClass.class));
```

Comment: Can't reproduce with 1.8.0_74. `return Optional.of(MyClass.class);` works as expected. Test: `public Optional<Class<? extends AnInterface<?>>> getCustomClass() {
  return Optional.of(MyClass.class);
 }
 interface AnInterface<T>{}
 class MyClass implements AnInterface<String> {}`

Comment: @Tunaki. It is strange, the code snippet in the question (which is the simplified version) actually works. The full version of the code does give compile error. It is definitely the return line that is causing the compiler error. it builds when returning Optional.empty();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast to the raw Optional type works but gives a warning.

```
public Optional<Class<? extends AnInterface<?>>> getCustomClass() {
    return (Optional)(Optional.of(MyClass.class));
}
```

Other solution:

```
public Optional<Class<? extends AnInterface<?>>> getCustomClass() {
    return Optional.<Class<? extends AnInterface<?>>>of(MyClass.class);
}
```